# How can I define groups based on another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, grouping, sequence

I need to define patches for each individual (id) based on the values of a variable (bmode).

bmode> 1.75 was classified as "ARS", bmode ≤ 1.75 was classified as "TRANS", intermediate values were designated as "IND".

Now, for 3 or more successive locations where ARS behavior has been predicted and ends after 3 or more consecutive locations with an estimated bmode ≤ 1.75 (TRANS or IND), I want to define a patch.

*EXAMPLE*

```
   lon      lat      id    bmode States pacth
-39.0436 -18.02402 7617.05 1.535    IND  
-39.0296 -18.02142 7617.05 1.844    ARS  1
-39.0588 -18.01219 7617.05 1.849    ARS  1
-38.9866 -18.06814 7617.05 1.871    ARS  1 
-38.9284 -18.07950 7617.05 1.894    IND  1
-38.8484 -18.12347 7617.05 1.892    ARS  1
-38.7905 -18.17230 7617.05 1.887    ARS  1
-38.7301 -18.20727 7617.05 1.895    ARS  1
-38.6774 -18.23565 7617.05 1.610   TRANS 
-38.6135 -18.27840 7617.05 1.567   TRANS 
-38.5408 -18.32210 7617.05 1.604    ARS  1
-38.4892 -18.35557 7617.05 1.690    ARS  1
-38.3138 -18.48745 7617.05 1.883   TRANS  
-38.2723 -18.52985 7617.05 1.900    IND  
-38.1407 -18.59948 7617.05 1.914   TRANS 
-38.2632 -18.56872 7617.05 1.889   TRANS 
-38.2459 -18.62644 7617.05 1.923    IND  
-38.2459 -18.62644 7617.05 1.923    ARS  2
-38.2459 -18.62644 7617.05 1.923    ARS  2
-38.2459 -18.62644 7617.05 1.923    ARS  2
-38.2459 -18.62644 7617.05 1.923    ARS  2
```

an example of my data:

```
structure(list(lon = c(-39.0436, -39.0296, -39.0588, -38.9866, 
-38.9284, -38.8484, -38.7905, -38.7301, -38.6774, -38.6135, -38.5408, 
-38.4892, -38.456, -38.3919, -38.3138, -38.2723, -38.1407, -38.2632, 
-38.2459, -38.2747, -38.2987, -38.3141, -38.3579, -38.392, -38.3896, 
-38.5027, -38.4808, -38.4915, -38.489, -38.5068, -38.5032, -38.5519, 
-38.5004, -38.6994, -38.6495, -38.6962, -38.7376, -38.7495, -38.7878, 
-38.8156, -38.8991, -38.9015, -38.8313, -38.7827, -38.7274, -38.6641, 
-38.6264, -38.5812, -38.4883, -38.5955, -38.5487, -38.5492, -38.5533, 
-38.5437, -38.5473, -38.5573, -38.525, -38.5888, -38.5459, -38.5435, 
-38.5415, -38.5414, -38.5196, -38.5127, -38.4951, -38.4738, -38.9912, 
-38.9995, -39.0267, -39.0119, -39.0007, -38.9933, -38.9914, -38.9781, 
-38.9652, -38.9589, -38.9566, -38.9364, -38.9324, -38.9192, -38.9151, 
-38.9127, -38.8989, -38.9196, -38.9466, -38.9368, -38.9212, -38.9372, 
-38.9017, -38.9075, -38.8863, -38.8964, -38.8982, -38.8865, -38.8728, 
-38.8712, -38.8494, -38.8808, -38.8027, -39.0087, -38.8636, -38.9025, 
-38.8767, -38.8935, -38.9005, -38.8938, -38.8937, -38.886, -38.9047, 
-38.9323, -38.9107, -38.9282, -38.9236, -38.9349, -38.9583, -38.9594, 
-38.9672, -38.9692, -38.984, -38.9818, -38.9836, -38.987, -39.0182, 
-38.9936, -39.2264, -39.204, -39.1369, -39.0456, -39.037, -39.0432, 
-39.053, -39.077, -39.0476, -38.9099, -38.5897, -38.3935, -38.3281, 
-38.2372, -38.1516, -39.4011, -39.4007, -39.381, -39.3143, -39.1883, 
-39.0848, -38.9683, -38.8596, -38.7436, -38.6208, -38.5017, -38.4042, 
-38.0645, -38.2054, -38.3541, -38.4964, -38.9432, -40.0811, -40.2097, 
-40.3045, -40.407, -40.6094, -40.8267, -40.9868, -41.1445, -41.2936, 
-41.4341, -41.5481, -41.6938, -39.3414, -39.3416, -39.3364, -39.3057, 
-39.2835, -39.1992, -39.2, -39.1865, -39.193, -39.2, -39.138, 
-39.2061, -39.3888, -39.4961, -39.4485, -39.5003, -39.4973, -39.4007, 
-39.2943, -39.2218, -39.1768, -39.2, -39.1, -38.9024, -38.8, 
-38.7925, -38.7005, -38.7008, -38.6006, -38.4998, -38.4049, -38.3037, 
-38.2385, -38.6517, -38.7984, -38.8361, -38.9007, -38.9004, -38.9071, 
-38.9349, -39, -39, -38.9007, -38.9968, -38.9964, -38.8311, -38.7335, 
-38.7004, -38.6765, -38.6955, -38.7974, -38.8001, -38.7009, -38.3625, 
-38.1997, -38.0234, -38.0097, -38.0992, -38.0534, -38.3628, -38.5987, 
-38.8076, -39.0003, -38.9904, -38.9892, -39.0679, -39.0001, -38.9249, 
-38.9079, -38.8996, -38.8108, -38.7311, -38.6322, -38.5035, -38.3582, 
-38.2991, -38.1159, -37.9348, -37.9852, -38.0631, -38.0841, -38.1274, 
-38.1185, -38.1229, -38.1062, -38.1396, -39.5231, -39.5125, -39.5115, 
-39.4903, -39.3941, -39.2933, -39.2113, -39.1423, -39.0942, -38.9999, 
-38.9014, -38.7997, -38.6007, -38.3894, -38.399, -38.4991, -38.5256, 
-38.698, -38.7655, -38.7009, -38.8008, -38.8841, -39.0272, -39.2955, 
-39.4852, -39.595, -39.6854, -39.7021, -39.8057, -39.9, -39.8877, 
-39.9994, -40.1642, -40.2322, -40.4992, -40.5, -40.4113, -40.5989, 
-40.7881, -40.7424, -40.606, -40.7425, -41.0996, -41.3999, -41.4023, 
-41.34, -41.2041, -41.1046, -41.2085, -41.2099, -41.2036, -41.2017, 
-41.101, -41.1847, -41.1793, -39.4168, -39.3946, -39.3536, -39.3344, 
-39.2869, -39.1997, -39.1979, -39.2196, -39.1841, -39.2093, -39.1753, 
-39.2057, -39.3412, -39.4862, -39.4655, -39.4503, -39.4887, -39.419, 
-39.3, -39.2001, -39.1905, -39.251, -39.2412, -39.2393, -39.189, 
-39.1328, -39.0298, -39.0582, -39.0574, -39.1507, -39.2034, -39.31, 
-39.3919, -39.4083, -39.0972, -39.1034, -39.1037, -39.1037, -39.2003, 
-39.2021, -39.1909, -39.2032, -39.2249, -39.1716, -39.1308, -39.1119, 
-39.3016, -39.2012, -39.0924, -38.8427, -38.9537, -39.2016, -39.2264, 
-39.1369, -38.8921, -39.1652, -39.0994, -38.9567, -39.1001, -39.2001, 
-39.2133, -39.0095, -38.8004, -38.4988, -38.3823, -38.2979, -38.4626, 
-38.4594, -38.5929, -38.861, -39.0009, -39.2179, -39.4608, -39.3378, 
-39.1553, -39.0425, -38.8626, -38.7, -38.8006, -38.8603, -38.8204, 
-38.6832, -38.955, -39.0196, -39.0073, -38.9121, -38.9039, -39.0539, 
-39.0748, -39.0152, -39.1352, -39.1422, -39.1786, -39.0992, -39.0336, 
-39.1611, -39.2103, -39.0897, -39.0961, -38.9633, -39.0134, -39.063, 
-38.8858, -38.8796, -38.6352, -38.8996, -38.6986, -38.4001, -38.9006, 
-39.0748, -39.0212, -39.1937, -38.9995, -38.891, -39.2152, -39.165, 
-38.9324, -38.7929, -38.741, -38.7026, -38.6067, -38.6719, -38.6988, 
-38.602, -38.6632, -38.597, -38.7529, -38.8518, -38.8986, -38.9405, 
-38.9459, -39.0497, -39.041, -38.8758, -38.6317, -38.5749, -38.4637, 
-38.5049, -38.704, -38.8656, -39.1987, -39.0995, -39.2397, -39.1808, 
-39.1631, -39.1943, -39.1972, -39.2266, -39.1289, -38.9703, -39.0081, 
-39.0031, -38.8355, -39.0236, -39.156, -39.2171, -39.2668, -39.3938, 
-39.2251, -39.2487, -39.2459, -39.141, -39.2095, -39.2157, -39.1825, 
-39.1866, -39.2747, -39.3956, -39.4894, -39.6178, -39.6336, -39.805, 
-39.8563, -40.1559, -40.3032, -40.2284, -40.2159, -40.1976, -40.177, 
-40.2168, -40.412, -40.462, -40.5478, -40.6394, -40.7387, -40.8329, 
-40.9126, -41.4315, -41.5374, -41.6369, -41.6646), lat = c(-18.02402, 
-18.02142, -18.01219, -18.06814, -18.0795, -18.12347, -18.1723, 
-18.20727, -18.23565, -18.2784, -18.3221, -18.35557, -18.40036, 
-18.43992, -18.48745, -18.52985, -18.59948, -18.56872, -18.62644, 
-18.64082, -18.68058, -18.71468, -18.75885, -18.77, -18.84994, 
-18.73186, -18.67437, -18.61312, -18.54152, -18.44923, -18.39034, 
-18.31269, -18.23386, -18.18817, -18.26355, -18.29528, -18.34884, 
-18.38988, -18.42106, -18.47147, -18.49385, -18.56982, -18.64914, 
-18.73588, -18.83264, -18.92236, -18.99768, -19.08327, -19.17413, 
-19.22802, -19.23173, -19.26408, -19.26973, -19.2927, -19.30199, 
-19.32348, -19.32296, -19.37331, -19.35441, -19.33839, -19.33868, 
-19.34228, -19.32594, -19.32932, -19.32141, -19.32491, -18.02301, 
-18.02199, -18.01843, -17.98781, -17.99012, -17.96139, -17.9304, 
-17.93597, -17.90333, -17.88244, -17.8396, -17.82455, -17.80983, 
-17.78898, -17.75384, -17.7464, -17.70714, -17.72363, -17.72188, 
-17.76075, -17.77719, -17.79589, -17.80181, -17.81844, -17.82241, 
-17.8301, -17.87149, -17.86871, -17.89045, -17.90092, -17.90884, 
-17.9377, -17.90441, -18.00828, -17.84275, -17.87748, -17.82021, 
-17.80229, -17.77197, -17.74166, -17.737, -17.69544, -17.69303, 
-17.67834, -17.67988, -17.66128, -17.67948, -17.64256, -17.67702, 
-17.607, -17.51752, -17.54804, -17.52722, -17.526, -17.53338, 
-17.54474, -17.51622, -17.52166, -17.86486, -17.90145, -18.0595, 
-18.14773, -18.14872, -18.15635, -18.17435, -18.19286, -18.23657, 
-18.38954, -18.7366, -18.89027, -18.93263, -19.04261, -19.17285, 
-18.4273, -18.44206, -18.4845, -18.4569, -18.42714, -18.36749, 
-18.36747, -18.32874, -18.32528, -18.28197, -18.24051, -18.48086, 
-18.85006, -19.03107, -19.24998, -19.44773, -19.52156, -22.10358, 
-22.21323, -22.32764, -22.44473, -22.59722, -22.73591, -22.92008, 
-23.12157, -23.29309, -23.43957, -23.5776, -23.72088, -18.44447, 
-18.44131, -18.44387, -18.44202, -18.48266, -18.35741, -18.34456, 
-18.32933, -18.35983, -18.39339, -18.36469, -18.3177, -18.35569, 
-18.43664, -18.45995, -18.53672, -18.56055, -18.58153, -18.47189, 
-18.37184, -18.19579, -18.0331, -18.00999, -18.12419, -18.07555, 
-17.99255, -18.01425, -18.06793, -18.05391, -17.94169, -17.97274, 
-17.77039, -17.67259, -17.19299, -17.07173, -16.96194, -16.98228, 
-16.9302, -16.96326, -16.84489, -16.80174, -16.63965, -16.50935, 
-16.44315, -16.46109, -16.34532, -16.22342, -16.18113, -16.05155, 
-15.95393, -15.90826, -15.90226, -15.83392, -16.00347, -16.0011, 
-16.00011, -15.98295, -16.15189, -16.28953, -16.35196, -16.43742, 
-16.55924, -16.72329, -16.8363, -16.88674, -17.02453, -17.12698, 
-17.32562, -17.57759, -17.74445, -17.88113, -17.88744, -17.88834, 
-17.87424, -17.97989, -18.11516, -18.14315, -18.27988, -18.3193, 
-18.33417, -18.37861, -18.5595, -18.62298, -18.73212, -18.86317, 
-18.94096, -18.60213, -18.60587, -18.5927, -18.54379, -18.57095, 
-18.45538, -18.30153, -18.18447, -18.0963, -18.15262, -18.09676, 
-18.22024, -18.28832, -18.37081, -18.66226, -18.8806, -19.09537, 
-19.27619, -19.48896, -19.47133, -19.4608, -19.33534, -19.42321, 
-19.45569, -19.51056, -19.58516, -19.67388, -19.81114, -19.85125, 
-20.03122, -20.27147, -20.46503, -20.61422, -20.80607, -20.8755, 
-20.97907, -21.20379, -21.36214, -21.61505, -21.87859, -22.05029, 
-22.17569, -22.41654, -22.50441, -22.48673, -22.63791, -22.44871, 
-22.82374, -22.73213, -22.68075, -22.5403, -22.41877, -22.32014, 
-22.29147, -22.2726, -18.49871, -18.50145, -18.52302, -18.40275, 
-18.50623, -18.34748, -18.33903, -18.27961, -18.35606, -18.39349, 
-18.36117, -18.32013, -18.3906, -18.42139, -18.49445, -18.5598, 
-18.55424, -18.56981, -18.47855, -18.34729, -18.22737, -18.72667, 
-18.73292, -18.73578, -18.82119, -18.89708, -18.80726, -18.57088, 
-18.61347, -18.47227, -18.55633, -18.65579, -18.7458, -18.82853, 
-19.06462, -19.1603, -19.21777, -19.29835, -19.29846, -19.30373, 
-19.40169, -19.2734, -19.1093, -19.06992, -19.02918, -18.96575, 
-18.77895, -18.54488, -18.36768, -18.38553, -18.40019, -18.40327, 
-18.28421, -18.40674, -18.55265, -18.33226, -18.43165, -18.48707, 
-18.43923, -18.34192, -18.37231, -18.37565, -18.32266, -18.39222, 
-18.46668, -18.36093, -18.32199, -18.4016, -18.48973, -18.66299, 
-18.83083, -18.69995, -18.9315, -18.88982, -18.88632, -18.97422, 
-19.14254, -19.38316, -19.23632, -19.2226, -19.17053, -19.26764, 
-19.28096, -19.29691, -19.44999, -19.37346, -19.21931, -19.28637, 
-19.26362, -19.26896, -19.25474, -19.26335, -19.29258, -19.02462, 
-19.05374, -18.83649, -18.64555, -18.54311, -18.44952, -18.39345, 
-18.45872, -18.47549, -18.32906, -18.43081, -18.50044, -18.46383, 
-18.40977, -18.38866, -18.36127, -18.42811, -18.61827, -18.85362, 
-19.02869, -19.30944, -19.34678, -19.37545, -19.44626, -19.39368, 
-19.26903, -19.1499, -19.17553, -19.03265, -18.86333, -18.91773, 
-18.83886, -18.86041, -18.82287, -18.76703, -18.6551, -18.60335, 
-18.60044, -18.66279, -18.7035, -18.85942, -19.03984, -19.06231, 
-19.01536, -19.06944, -19.05, -19.1322, -18.98444, -18.96721, 
-19.12118, -19.04001, -19.03243, -18.38454, -18.39538, -18.41778, 
-18.41852, -18.35118, -18.13682, -18.15383, -17.95502, -17.93224, 
-17.95541, -18.06734, -18.13123, -18.19873, -18.39062, -18.67687, 
-18.79011, -19.10935, -19.12687, -19.27263, -19.21628, -19.12258, 
-19.24072, -19.3667, -19.48665, -19.60648, -19.75132, -19.93728, 
-20.01678, -20.26459, -20.47156, -20.48558, -20.52792, -20.56808, 
-20.58172, -20.67554, -20.70199, -20.85253, -20.96789, -21.09977, 
-21.2384, -21.38706, -21.52404, -22.26495, -22.40997, -22.56755, 
-22.62307), id = c(7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 
7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7617.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 7618.05, 
10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 
10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 10946.05, 
10946.05, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 
20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 
20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 
20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 20162.03, 
20162.03, 20162.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 
20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 20687.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 
21791.03, 21791.03, 21791.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 
21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 
21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 
21792.03, 21792.03, 21792.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 21800.03, 
21800.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 
21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 
21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 
21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 
21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 
21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 
21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03, 21809.03), bmode = c(1.535, 
1.844, 1.849, 1.871, 1.894, 1.892, 1.887, 1.895, 1.91, 1.867, 
1.904, 1.89, 1.894, 1.88, 1.883, 1.9, 1.914, 1.889, 1.923, 1.901, 
1.908, 1.904, 1.918, 1.921, 1.899, 1.869, 1.9, 1.906, 1.903, 
1.902, 1.907, 1.913, 1.898, 1.9, 1.921, 1.91, 1.919, 1.909, 1.932, 
1.907, 1.917, 1.869, 1.911, 1.887, 1.914, 1.895, 1.911, 1.925, 
1.915, 1.897, 1.92, 1.904, 1.93, 1.924, 1.93, 1.91, 1.909, 1.884, 
1.898, 1.916, 1.909, 1.913, 1.917, 1.912, 1.907, NA, 1.546, 1.873, 
1.898, 1.926, 1.941, 1.929, 1.938, 1.928, 1.934, 1.926, 1.914, 
1.932, 1.936, 1.928, 1.938, 1.923, 1.925, 1.906, 1.905, 1.946, 
1.945, 1.956, 1.94, 1.949, 1.942, 1.957, 1.943, 1.954, 1.94, 
1.945, 1.934, 1.947, 1.938, 1.965, 1.941, 1.958, 1.952, 1.953, 
1.956, 1.95, 1.954, 1.939, 1.944, 1.95, 1.934, 1.955, 1.956, 
1.952, 1.933, 1.976, 1.945, 1.947, 1.95, 1.95, 1.952, 1.946, 
1.931, NA, 1.525, 1.337, 1.341, 1.339, 1.369, 1.364, 1.402, 1.368, 
1.346, 1.261, 1.257, 1.316, 1.326, 1.332, 1.323, 1.529, 1.603, 
1.634, 1.637, 1.67, 1.665, 1.663, 1.659, 1.673, 1.646, 1.688, 
1.507, 1.62, 1.686, 1.621, 1.673, 1.634, 1.597, 1.603, 1.616, 
1.593, 1.594, 1.579, 1.603, 1.579, 1.586, 1.599, 1.603, 1.619, 
1.512, 1.253, 1.199, 1.185, 1.157, 1.153, 1.149, 1.163, 1.129, 
1.102, 1.097, 1.057, 1.05, 1.057, 1.056, 1.064, 1.067, 1.04, 
1.035, 1.021, 1.022, 1.055, 1.024, 1.033, 1.046, 1.057, 1.066, 
1.068, 1.039, 1.064, 1.053, 1.018, 1.023, 1.017, 1.031, 1.059, 
1.08, 1.07, 1.087, 1.056, 1.034, 1.034, 1.072, 1.07, 1.062, 1.032, 
1.043, 1.039, 1.036, 1.034, 1.049, 1.057, 1.035, 1.018, 1.015, 
1.055, 1.083, 1.032, 1.082, 1.004, 1.008, 1.007, 1.043, 1.077, 
1.053, 1.036, 1.024, 1.007, 1.016, 1.034, 1.059, 1.045, 1.033, 
1.038, 1.029, 1.031, 1.026, 1.16, 1.08, 1.069, 1.06, 1.051, 1.05, 
1.043, 1.071, NA, 1.503, 1.312, 1.261, 1.237, 1.158, 1.115, 1.097, 
1.117, 1.123, 1.127, 1.113, 1.065, 1.04, 1.085, 1.027, 1.028, 
1.026, 1.035, 1.089, 1.132, 1.124, 1.122, 1.051, 1.05, 1.063, 
1.16, 1.109, 1.096, 1.074, 1.023, 1.04, 1.03, 1.033, 1.048, 1.072, 
1.054, 1.064, 1.025, 1.028, 1.041, 1.081, 1.022, 1.02, 1.178, 
1.318, 1.494, 1.694, 1.681, 1.338, 1.26, 1.19, 1.188, 1.25, 1.207, 
NA, 1.526, 1.618, 1.647, 1.681, 1.65, 1.617, 1.63, 1.652, 1.62, 
1.64, 1.607, 1.602, 1.596, 1.636, 1.708, 1.716, 1.684, 1.618, 
1.569, 1.583, NA, 1.508, 1.645, 1.728, 1.785, 1.828, 1.647, 1.866, 
1.766, 1.813, 1.619, 1.629, 1.633, 1.66, 1.66, 1.774, 1.769, 
1.748, 1.732, 1.684, 1.812, 1.605, 1.747, 1.765, 1.745, 1.628, 
1.491, 1.393, 1.578, 1.826, 1.586, 1.713, 1.836, 1.523, 1.988, 
1.94, 1.676, 1.861, 1.63, 1.754, 1.712, 1.524, 1.414, 1.568, 
1.734, 1.751, 1.726, 1.597, 1.386, 1.313, 1.701, 1.698, 1.923, 
1.596, 1.649, 1.507, 1.315, 1.951, 1.685, 1.765, 1.772, 1.882, 
1.69, 1.706, 1.851, 1.647, 1.859, 1.72, 1.789, 1.748, 1.757, 
1.861, 1.761, 1.824, 1.848, 1.464, 1.65, 1.682, 1.707, 1.828, 
1.766, 1.789, 1.868, 1.647, 1.93, 1.944, 1.413, 1.99, 1.497, 
1.689, 1.372, 1.61, 1.288, 1.808, 1.874, 1.623, 1.627, 1.635, 
1.645, 1.701, 1.781, 1.548, 1.816, 1.778, 1.769, 1.787, 1.721, 
1.774, 1.72, 1.736, 1.747, 1.731, 1.719, 1.457, 1.742, 1.733, 
1.792, 1.672, 1.617, 1.542, 1.909, 1.792, 1.834, 1.742, NA, 1.528, 
1.78, 1.782, 1.859, 1.819, 1.844, 1.795, 1.87, 1.734, 1.838, 
1.772, 1.883, 1.809, 1.654, 1.722, 1.748, 1.846, 1.78, 1.814, 
1.776, 1.813, 1.75, 1.807, 1.806, 1.79, 1.773, 1.753, 1.803, 
1.655, 1.841, 1.817, 1.856, 1.832, 1.836, 1.766, 1.791, 1.742, 
1.728, 1.734, 1.737, 1.714, 1.735, 1.709, 1.744, 1.803, 1.881
), States = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ARS", "IND", 
"TRANS"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 
119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 431L, 
432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 450L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 
481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 
496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 
507L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 
518L, 519L, 520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 
532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 
543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 
555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 564L, 565L, 
566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 575L, 576L, 
577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 587L, 
588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 
599L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 610L, 
611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 619L, 620L, 621L, 
622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 630L, 631L, 632L, 
633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 
644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 
655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 663L, 664L, 665L, 
666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 674L, 675L, 676L, 
677L, 678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 
688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 696L, 697L, 698L, 
699L, 700L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 707L, 708L, 709L, 
710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 718L, 719L, 720L, 
721L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 730L, 731L, 
732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 741L, 742L, 
743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 750L, 751L, 752L, 753L, 
754L, 755L, 756L, 757L, 758L, 759L, 760L, 761L, 762L, 763L, 764L, 
765L, 766L, 767L, 768L, 769L, 770L, 771L, 772L, 773L, 774L, 775L, 
776L, 777L, 778L, 779L, 780L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 785L, 786L, 
787L, 788L, 789L, 790L, 791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 796L, 797L, 
798L, 799L, 800L, 801L, 802L, 803L, 804L, 805L, 806L, 807L, 808L, 
809L, 810L, 811L, 812L, 813L, 814L, 815L, 816L, 817L, 818L, 819L, 
820L, 821L, 822L, 823L, 824L, 825L, 826L, 827L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The following will get you some of the way.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(case_when(States != 'ARS' ~ TRUE,
                                  States == 'ARS' & 
                                  lag(States != 'ARS') ~ TRUE, 
                                  TRUE ~ FALSE))) %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  mutate(isPatch = if_else('ARS' %in% States & n() > 2, TRUE, FALSE),
         tempPatch = if_else(row_number() == min(row_number()) & 
                             isPatch == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(patch = if_else(isPatch == TRUE, cumsum(tempPatch), NA_integer_)) %>%
  select(colnames(df), patch)

# # A tibble: 500 x 6
# # Groups:   id [9]
#      lon   lat    id bmode States patch
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <int>
# 1  -39.0 -18.0 7617.  1.54 IND       NA
# 2  -39.0 -18.0 7617.  1.84 ARS        1
# 3  -39.1 -18.0 7617.  1.85 ARS        1
# 4  -39.0 -18.1 7617.  1.87 ARS        1
# 5  -38.9 -18.1 7617.  1.89 ARS        1
# 6  -38.8 -18.1 7617.  1.89 ARS        1
# 7  -38.8 -18.2 7617.  1.89 ARS        1
# 8  -38.7 -18.2 7617.  1.90 ARS        1
# 9  -38.7 -18.2 7617.  1.91 ARS        1
# 10 -38.6 -18.3 7617.  1.87 ARS        1
# # … with 490 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rjen, but when applying the suggestion to my data nothing happens. The dataframe remains the same. Do you know why?

Comment: Another observation @rjen was considered the "id"?
Will the numeric categories "1", "2", "3" be repeated for each "id" ... and so on? it looks like it will be sequential.

Comment: Edit made: The solution now applies to each individual ```id``` (group). Regarding the issue of 'nothing happens': How could you find the error in the original solution if it does nothing on your end? Have you tried saving the output? What does it say in the console when you run the solution?

Comment: @AnneElise: Please see my comment above.

Comment: I realized that there was no mention of the "id" column, so I thought that the sequence would not consider individuals.
When applying the suggestion, the "patch" column is not created, it continues with the same previous columns, without any changes. No error appears.@rjen

Comment: I saved the output to another object and it worked! @rjen

Comment: how to insert the name of the "id" after the number of the "patch"? something like: "1_7617.05", "2_7617.05"? Or any other suggestions that can differentiate the patches for each individual.

Comment: From my phone (untested): Try loading library(stringr) and adding %>% mutate(patch = if_else(!is.na(patch), str_c(id, patch, sep = “_”), patch))

Comment: showed an error.
so I just applied the function *str_c ()*: df$patch_id <- str_c(df$id, df$patch, sep = "_"). It worked! :D

Comment: "patch" keeps appearing with sequential numbers. The number 1 does not appear again, for example, for each "id".

Comment: @AnneElise: I am not sure what you mean. I just ran the code from my post on your data again. On my end, ```patch``` works with id as the grouping variable (i.e. the group numbers in ```patch``` start from 1 and increase for each ```id``` - to the extent that there are line-ups of 'ARS' in States that are longer than two).

Comment: the sequence of the "patch" column does not start again (from 1) for each id.

Comment: Got it. Thing is, it works as it is supposed to when I run it. Have you tried pasting my solution into a blank script and running on your data anew?

Comment: I found the problem. It was with group_by function, I nedded to detach package plyr.

Comment: Last doubt, @rjen: It's not clear to me if the "patch" ends after 3 or more consecutive states TRANS or IND in this code.

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the requirement. Please update the example of your desired output in order to have it reflect what you are after (if it doesn't do so already).

Comment: I now think I see what you are after. As it does not provide the sought after output, please unaccept my answer as a solution.